# SMTPAuthenticationError 535: In development

Tags: python, django, smtp, settings, smtplib

I am creating a password reset utility and I am getting this error in my localhost web server:

```
SMTPAuthenticationError at /password-reset/
(535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials i10sm742924qkn.126 - gsmtp')
```

I have looked at other posts, turned on less secure apps, stored the in the password and username in the environment variable settings correctly ( I know because I printed them in shell. Output came out as expected ), and did the display unlock captcha. I am running code in windows powershell.
This is my settings configuration:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND="django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('HOST_USER')
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('HOST_PASSWORD')
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow access to less secured apps by switching allow less secure apps ON from your mail account settings. If you are using google account, then you can follow this link: https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Comment: That is already on. Thank You for the suggestion though.